# MySQL REGEXP match postcode

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have a database full of postcodes and I'm creating a search which looks up a prefix of a postcode for example:

```
AB, BR, G, GU
```

Now what I can't work out and I've tried various `LIKE`, `RLIKE` and `REGEXP` but can't seem to work it out.

If you searched `G` I want it to return only `G1`, `G2` etc. What it currently is doing is outputting `G1`, `G2`, `GU1`, `GU2` how can I stop it from showing `GU` results?

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from your_table
where postcode REGEXP 'G[0-9]+'
```

### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac68c/4)

Comment: Thanks this worked, although I needed to add `^` to the start. Thanks!